# “Noun1+Preposition+Noun2” VS. “Noun2+Noun1”

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, attributive-nouns, compound-nouns

If i want to write sentences such as the following ones,

- **1** Some people value **the beliefs in respect**.
- **2**)The president gave him **an approval to the policy**.
- **3**) there is **a demand for water** in some poor countries.
- **4**) He suggest the **need for leadership**.
- **5**) A lot of children are developing **a habit for smoking**.
- **6**) Loneliness is cited as **a reason for suicide**. 
  ........
  Do they change in the meaning when I turn them into this reduced form?

> - 1) Some people value **respect beliefs**
> - 2) The president gave him **a policy approval**
> - 3) There is **a water demand** in some poor countries.
> - 4) He suggests **the leadership need**.
> - 5) A lot of children are developing **a smoking habit**.
> - 6) loneliness is cited as **a suicide reason**.

If they do change in meaning, could you please provide me with any rule i need to follow when i want to reduce the nouns with prepositions to keep the meaning consistent?

Comment: The first modified sentence should be--"Some people value respecting beliefs".

Answer (score 1):

> - 1A. Some people value the beliefs in respect.
> - 1B. Some people value respect beliefs

Neither of these is correct, and I am not at all sure what the intended meaning is. It might be:

> Some people value respecting the beliefs of others.

---

> - 2A. The president gave him an approval to the policy.
> - 2B. The president gave him a policy approval

2A is incorrect. "...an approval **of** the policy" would be valid, but 2B is better, if still awkward

---

> - 3A. There is a demand for water in some poor countries.
> - 3B. There is a water demand in some poor countries.

3A is correct and very common. 3B is probably not incorrect, but it feels awkward and is not common.

---

> - 4A. He suggest the need for leadership.
> - 4B. He suggests the leadership need.

Neither of these is good. "leadership need" is awkward and unclear. In 4A it should be "suggests" because He is singular, so:

> 4C. He suggests the need for leadership.

---

> - 5A A lot of children are developing a habit for smoking.
> - 5B A lot of children are developing a smoking habit.

In 5A it should be "a habit of smoking" or better "the habit of smoking". 5B is correct and very common.

---

> - 6A Loneliness is cited as a reason for suicide
> - 6A Loneliness is cited as a suicide reason

6A is correct and common. 6B is a little less common, but correct and has the same meaning.

Comment: it seems like normally “Noun1+Preposition+Noun2” is clearer than “Noun2+Noun1”